# SVG CSS Colors style

Tags: css, svg, colors, svg-animate, animate-cc

i'm Elia graphic designer. It's a pleasure to be here with you. I've a big question. I need to do an animate svg. Actually i use Adobe CC Animate with a plugin. This is the code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="550" height="400" baseProfile="basic" image-rendering="optimizeSpeed">
  <g overflow="visible">
    <path fill="#3C3C3B" d="M39.8 0H0v2.25h39.8V0z"/>
    <path fill="#898989" d="M2.2 2.25v15.9l4.7 3.6v55.9h30.65V2.25H2.2z"/>
    <path fill="#FFEC00" d="M26.25 21.2H17.5v4.5h8.75v-4.5z"/>
    <path fill="#3C3C3B" d="M38.3 36.15H19.35v3.2H38.3v-3.2zM31.6 41.95H19.4v3.15h12.2v-3.15zM39.4 46.8H4.3V49h35.1v-2.2z"/>
    <path fill="#575756" d="M17.85 70.95q1.8 1.8 4.4 1.8 2.55 0 4.4-1.8 1.8-1.85 1.8-4.4 0-2.6-1.8-4.4-1.85-1.8-4.4-1.8-2.6 0-4.4 1.85-1.85 1.8-1.8 4.35 0 2.6 1.8 4.4zM83.75 74v3.65H4.35V74H2.2v3.65h1.05v13.9H85v-13.9h1V74h-2.25z"/>
    <path fill="#575756" d="M75.1 72H52.55v4.2H75.1V72z"/>
    <path fill="#3C3C3B" d="M79.35 76.15H46.4v1.55h32.95v-1.55zM78.55 60.45q0-6.1-4.3-10.45-4.35-4.3-10.45-4.3T53.35 50q-4.3 4.35-4.3 10.45t4.3 10.4q4.35 4.3 10.45 4.3t10.45-4.3q4.3-4.3 4.3-10.4z"/>
    <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M71.7 68.35q3.3-3.3 3.3-7.9v-.05q0-4.65-3.25-7.9-3.3-3.3-7.95-3.3-4.6 0-7.9 3.25-3.25 3.3-3.25 7.9Q52.6 65 55.9 68.3q3.25 3.3 7.9 3.3 4.6 0 7.9-3.25z"/>
    <path fill="#575756" d="M65.15 58.5q-.15-.1-.75-.35l1.75-8.6q-2.3-.7-4.55 0l1.75 8.55q-.45.1-.8.3l-4.85-7.3q-2.1 1.1-3.25 3.2l7.3 4.85q-.2.25-.35.75l-8.6-1.75q-.7 2.3 0 4.55l8.7-1.85q.05.4.3.8l-7.3 4.8q1.2 2.2 3.25 3.2l4.75-7.3q.5.3.75.35l-1.75 8.6q2.3.7 4.55 0l-1.75-8.55q.6-.1.8-.25l4.85 7.3q2.2-1.2 3.2-3.25l-7.3-4.8q.3-.4.35-.75l8.5 1.8q.7-2.25 0-4.55L66.15 60q-.1-.5-.3-.75l7.3-4.9q-1.1-2-3.2-3.15l-4.8 7.3z"/>
    <path fill="#3C3C3B" d="M65 40.3h-2.35v7.95H65V40.3zM25.45 80.95H18.2v7.25h7.25v-7.25z"/>
    <path fill="#59595B" d="M19 84.6q0 1.15.85 2 .8.85 2 .85 1.15 0 2-.85.8-.85.8-2 0-1.2-.8-2-.85-.85-2-.85h-.05q-1.15 0-2 .85-.8.8-.8 2z"/>
    <path fill="#FFEC00" d="M25.85 64.75h-7.2v3.7h7.2v-3.7z"/>
    <path fill="#9C9B9B" d="M65.2 61.85q.6-.55.6-1.4 0-.8-.6-1.4-.55-.6-1.4-.6-.8 0-1.4.6-.6.6-.6 1.4 0 .85.6 1.4.6.6 1.4.6.85 0 1.4-.6z"/>
    <path fill="#868686" d="M70.6 82.75H57.05v2.4H70.6v-2.4z"/>
  </g></svg>
```

Unfortunalty the colors are inside the path. I need the svg with color in CSS Style. If i try to generate a SVG in illustrator this is the result (look the  part into the **):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="basic" id="_x31__9_"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 450 450"
     xml:space="preserve">
**<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#EAB38B;}
    .st1{fill:#97B6C4;}
</style>**
<g id="_x34_">
    <g id="_x32__6_">
        <g id="_x32__5_">
            <g id="_x32_">
                <g id="_x31_6_1_">
                    <g>
                        <path class="st0" d="M114.9,145.6c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0l-0.8,0.1c-0.8,0.1-0.6,0.3-1.4,0.4c-1.6,0.1-3.2,0-4.8,0.1
                            c-1.5,0.1-2.1-0.9-3-2c-1.4-1.8-3.7-3.5-4.3-5.8c-0.2-0.9-0.6-1.9-0.7-2.8c-0.1-0.8,0-1.5-0.2-2.3c-0.2-0.7-0.9-2.1,0.3-2
                            c0.3,0,0.9,0.1,1.1,0.3c0.5,0.4,0.9,1.1,1.1,1.7c0.1,0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4c0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.9,1.7c0.1-1.6,0-2.9-0.2-4.5
                            c-0.1-1.3-0.2-2.6-0.3-3.9c-0.1-1.8-0.3-3.7-0.4-5.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1.1c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4
                            c0,0,0-0.1,0.1-0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.6-0.5,1.3-0.5,2-0.2c0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c0,0,0,0,0,0
                            c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0.1,1.3,0.2,2.5,0.2,3.8c0.1,0.9,0.1,1.7,0.2,2.6
                            c0.1,0.8,0.2,2,0.5,2.3c0-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.7c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.1-0.7c0-0.4-0.2-1,0-1.5c0.2-0.8,1.5-1,2.1-0.6
                            c0.7,0.4,0.7,1.3,0.8,2c0,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.4,0.6c0.2-0.6,0.2-1.7,0.5-2c0.4-0.6,1.4-0.7,2-0.3c0.9,0.6,0.8,2.1,0.9,3
                            c0.2-0.2,0.1-0.8,0.3-1c0.2-0.3,0.7-0.5,1-0.5c1.5,0,1.4,1.8,1.5,2.9c0.3,1.9,0.4,3.8,0.4,5.7c0,0.9-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.8
                            c-0.2,0.8-0.7,1.5-0.8,2.3c-0.1,0.7,0.1,1.4,0.1,2.1c0,0.4,0,0.6,0.1,0.8C115,145.5,115,145.6,114.9,145.6z"/>
                        <polygon class="st1" points="116,144.6 104.5,145.2 105.1,148.4 116,147.3                        "/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm looking for a solutions with a converter or something else.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is stopping you from using CSS? And how do the two SVGs relate to each other?

Comment: `fill` is a so-called [presentation attribute](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes), which means it is a CSS property that can also be written as a XML attribute (with a lower specificity). Nothing prevents you from animating `fill` with CSS.

Comment: Hi Turnip, thanks for your response. The problem is the code that generates Adobe animate CC. If you see my  1st exemple the colors are defined in the path and don't in the CSS Style like te 2nd exemple. Ive not a problem with the animation, i've a problem whit te colors attributes. SVG are jusy examples 
they do not have to relate. I need colors into the CSS because i put this SVG into a software. If i have CSS colors like 1st, i'm able to change colors. do it by hand is crazy.. there is a converter or something else?